# Access BIOS on external monitor - broken screen of MSI GS70 notebook with HDMI output only

Tags: display, bios, hdmi, windows-installer

I have MSI GS70 notebook and the screen broke. I successfully use HDMI output to external monitor to work with the notebook. However, I would like to completely remove old system (Win 8.1) and install new system from the scratch (Win 10). For that I need to see BIOS on the external monitor.

I have read many forum topics and I did not find anything that would work for me. So I decided to start new post on the topic and particular machine. I hope that somebody will have experience with MSI and will show me how to do it.

First of all I have disconnected notebook screen. However, after hitting F11 during startup and entering BIOS, it shows only dark screen, while when starting normally the signal is transmitted to external screen successfully.

I have disabled internal monitor in Devices Manager, as well as Intel intergrated graphics, leaving just external monitor and NVIDIA graphics. I can see now only external monitor in NVIDIA panel but strangely enough, I see external and internal monitor in Screen Resolution panel (right click on the desktop).

I also tried switching the signal path after entering BIOS with Fn+F2 but while I can confirm it working in Windows, in BIOS it does not help and I still see dark screen whatever I press.

Can somebody help me? Ultimate goal is to install new Windows 10 system, I do not need to see BIOS for anything else.

Thank you :)